# Sudo works for a whole day and then stops working until a reboot

Tags: terminal, sudo

I currently have admin access to a Macbook Pro running OSX 10.8.4.  I have been sudoing at the terminal for the whole day with no restart until sudo stops working.  I rebooted the operating system and it is working again.  Is there a configuration that is preventing sudo from working after certain number of hours?

My `sudoers` file has with username `theuser`:

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep += "BLOCKSIZE"
Defaults    env_keep += "COLORFGBG COLORTERM"
Defaults    env_keep += "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING"
Defaults    env_keep += "CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME"
Defaults    env_keep += "LINES COLUMNS"
Defaults    env_keep += "LSCOLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
Defaults    env_keep += "TZ"
Defaults    env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
Defaults    env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
Defaults:theuser timestamp_timeout=30

# Runas alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

**EDIT**

The issue is happening again and after tailing `/var/log/system.log`, I see the following message:

```
failed to create secure channel: STATUS_NO_TRUST_SAM_ACCOUNT (0xC000018B)
```

Any idea what the above might mean?

Comment: What does "stop working" mean: error message, just doesn't change user or what? Also: what is in the logs?

Comment: Stops working is when I sudo and enter the password, it asks me to try again.  What is the location of the logs for sudoing?

Comment: You should check the sudo log (syslog). You can do this using the Console app (found in /Applications/Utilities